# Approximate subset sum with two-dimensional vectors

Tags: optimization, approximation, integer-programming, quadratic-programming

Consider the following optimization problem:

> Given $n\leq 10^3$ vectors $v_i\in\mathbb{R}^2$, all of which are small, i.e., $\|v_i\| \leq 1$, find a subset $S$ of them that minimizes
>   $ \| w + \sum_{i\in S} v_i \|^2$, where $w$ is a fixed known vector.

I know that this can be reduced to an unconstrained 0-1 quadratic program (with unknowns $x_i\in\{0,1\}$, $x_i=1$ whenever $i\in S$), but that is a hard problem in general.

However, since the constraints are so specific, is there a way to get a reasonably simple efficient approximation algorithm for it? One that doesn't involve integer programming? It's not even clear to me how to efficiently implement a greedy algorithm for it.

Are there special cases of this problem that are easier? For example, would it help if all the vectors were unit length, $\|v_i\|=1$?

Comment: Related: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/45718/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/33788/755.  And maybe: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/56158/755

Comment: Your problem is the [Closest Vector Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_problem#Closest_vector_problem_.28CVP.29) (CVP) in an [integer lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(group)).  In general, the CVP is fairly hard.  However, you are working in only 2 dimensions, so the problem might become tractable.  It's known that the 2D SVP can be solved in polynomial time ([algorithm due to Gauss](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/626263/14578)) if you start with only 2 vectors.  I don't know if it is solvable if you start with $n>2$ vectors, or if it extends to the CVP.

Comment: @D.W. I don't follow you: in a lattice, the coefficients are just arbitrary integers. How do you reduce the 0-1 problem to a lattice problem?

Comment: You are absolutely right; my mistake.  I overlooked that we need the coefficients to be not just integers, but either zero or one.  To try to save my idea: I think we still might be able to formulate as a lattice problem by replacing the vector $(x_i,y_i)$ with a vector of the form $(x_i,y_i,0,0,\dots,0,K,0,\dots,0)$ where $K$ is a sufficiently large constant, but then we're not in a lattice of dimension two.  That might lead to an approximation algorithm using LLL lattice reduction, but I haven't thought about it carefully.

Comment: Why isn't the objective function to be minimized the following? $$ \left\|  \left( \sum_{i\in S} v_i \right) - w \right\|_2^2$$

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo It's the same thing ($w\leftrightarrow -w$).

Answer (score 2):

Let $\rm V$ be the $2 \times n$ matrix whose $i$-th column is vector $\rm v_i$. We have the Boolean optimization problem in $\mathrm z \in \{0,1\}^n$

$$\min_{\mathrm z \in \{0,1\}^n} \| \mathrm V \mathrm z + \mathrm w \|_2^2$$

Let

$$\rm z = \frac 12 (x + 1_n)$$

where $\mathrm x \in \{\pm 1\}^n$. Hence, we have an instance of the **Boolean least-squares** (BLS) problem

$$\min_{\mathrm x \in \{\pm 1\}^n} \| \mathrm A \mathrm x - \mathrm b \|_2^2$$

where

$$\rm A = \frac 12 V \qquad \qquad \qquad b = - \left( \frac 12 V 1_n + w \right)$$

Since $\{\pm 1\}$ is the solution set of the quadratic equation $x_i^2 = 1$, we have the following (non-convex) [quadratically constrained quadratic program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratically_constrained_quadratic_program) (QCQP) in $\mathrm x \in \mathbb R^n$

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \| \mathrm A \mathrm x - \mathrm b \|_2^2\\ \text{subject to} & x_i^2 = 1 \quad \forall i \in \{1,2,\dots,n\}\end{array}$$

Exhaustive evaluation of the objective function at all $2^n$ points is only feasible for small $n$.

---

#### SDP relaxation

Note that

$$\begin{array}{rl} \| \mathrm A \mathrm x - \mathrm b \|_2^2 &= (\mathrm A \mathrm x - \mathrm b)^{\top} (\mathrm A \mathrm x - \mathrm b)\\ &= \mbox{tr} \left( (\mathrm A \mathrm x - \mathrm b)  (\mathrm A \mathrm x - \mathrm b)^{\top} \right)\\ &= \mbox{tr} \left( \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm A & -\mathrm b\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm x\\ 1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm x\\ 1\end{bmatrix}^{\top} \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm A & -\mathrm b\end{bmatrix}^{\top} \right)\\ &= \mbox{tr} \left( \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm A^{\top}\\ -\mathrm b^{\top}\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm A & -\mathrm b\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm x\\ 1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm x^{\top} & 1\end{bmatrix} \right)\\ &= \mbox{tr} \left( \begin{bmatrix} \,\,\,\, \mathrm A^{\top} \mathrm A & -\mathrm A^{\top}\mathrm b\\ -\mathrm b^{\top}\mathrm A & \,\,\,\, \mathrm b^{\top}\mathrm b\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm x \mathrm x^{\top} & \mathrm x\\ \mathrm x^{\top} & 1\end{bmatrix} \right)\end{array}$$

Since $\mathrm x \in \{\pm 1\}^n$, all $n$ entries on the main diagonal of $\mathrm x \mathrm x^{\top}$ are equal to $1$. Thus,

$$\begin{bmatrix} \mathrm x \mathrm x^{\top} & \mathrm x\\ \mathrm x^{\top} & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

is symmetric, positive semidefinite and has only ones on its main diagonal, i.e., it is a *correlation* matrix. Its rank is $1$. Let

$$\mathrm C := \begin{bmatrix} \,\,\,\, \mathrm A^{\top} \mathrm A & -\mathrm A^{\top}\mathrm b\\ -\mathrm b^{\top}\mathrm A & \,\,\,\, \mathrm b^{\top}\mathrm b\end{bmatrix}$$

Hence, the BLS problem can be written as the following *rank-constrained* optimization problem in $(n+1) \times (n+1)$ symmetric matrix $\rm Y$

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \langle \mathrm C , \mathrm Y \rangle\\ \text{subject to} & y_{ii} = 1, \quad \forall i \in \{1,2,\dots,n+1\}\\ & \mathrm Y \succeq \mathrm O_{n+1}\\ & \mbox{rank} (\mathrm Y) = 1\end{array}$$

which is a hard problem due to the rank constraint. *Relaxing* the optimization problem above by discarding the rank constraint, we then obtain the following **semidefinite program** (SDP) in $\rm Y$

$$\boxed{\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \langle \mathrm C , \mathrm Y \rangle\\ \text{subject to} & y_{ii} = 1, \quad \forall i \in \{1,2,\dots,n+1\}\\ & \mathrm Y \succeq \mathrm O_{n+1}\end{array}}$$

which is convex and computationally tractable. This SDP relaxation provides a **lower bound** on the minimum of the original BLS problem. In the very, very fortunate case where the optimal solution of the SDP happens to be rank-$1$, we have solved the BLS problem.

---

#### References

- Alexandre d'Aspremont, Stephen Boyd, [Relaxations and Randomized Methods for Nonconvex QCQPs](https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee364b/lectures/relaxations.pdf), EE392o, Stanford University, Autumn 2003.
- Stephen Boyd, [Convex Optimization](http://www.mathtube.org/sites/default/files/lecture-notes/Boyd_Stephen.pdf), IAM-PIMS, Vancouver, 3/15/04.
- Laurent El Ghaoui, [Homework Assignment #1](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Eelghaoui/Teaching/EE227A/hw1.pdf), EE227A, January 2012.
- [Semidefinite relaxation for Boolean least squares](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/755688/339790), Mathematics Stack Exchange.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you know if size-$n=10^3$ SDP problems should be considered feasible? It seems like it might be too big.

Comment: @Kirill That should be feasible. Take a look at [Do they use semidefinite programming in industry?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/15926/20417).

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following approach to approximate this problem.

First, construct an efficient data structure using your vectors that can perform Nearest Neighbor related searching, such as a KD Tree. Then, formulate your problem as an optimization that's a function of $N$, the number of nearest neighbors you will compute. To get there, we can do the following with the cost function:

\begin{align}
J &= \left\lVert w + \sum_{i \in S} v_i\right\Vert^2 \\
&= \frac{N^2}{N^2}\left\lVert w + \sum_{i \in S_N} v_i\right\Vert^2 \\
&= N^2\left\lVert \frac{w}{N} + \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i \in S_N} v_i\right\Vert^2
\end{align}

Note that $S_N$ is then an approximate solution for $S$. We can then approximate this problem by choosing $N$ such that we generate a set of vectors, which can be represented by the index set $S_N$, that are the $N$ nearest neighbors to $\frac{-w}{N}$. The logic is that selecting $N$ nearest neighbors from $\lbrace v_i \rbrace$ about $\frac{-w}{N}$ will produce a value for $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i \in S_N} v_i$ close to $\frac{-w}{N}$ and in turn help minimize the norm.

The resulting optimization then ends up being:

\begin{align}
N^{*} = \arg \min_{N} N^2 \left\lVert \frac{w}{N} + \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i \in S_N} v_i\right\Vert^2
\end{align}

How you go about tackling the above optimization is then up to you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Does this assume that the vectors are uniformly distributed? I don't want to assume that, so I'm not sure about the step where the average of $N$ nearest neighbours should be close to $\frac{-w}{N}$.

Comment: @Kirill This approximation scheme does not depend on that, though I expect it would perform better if a subset of the vectors were at least uniformly distributed near $\frac{-w}{N}$. The level of accuracy this might achieve certainly is dependent on the distribution of the vectors.